# Is there a better way to listen table changes in Node JS without using setInterval() function

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, setinterval

I am learning `Node JS` integration with `Codeigniter`. The process is working perfect.

**I am showing some real time notification when some changes occur in the database(MySql)**

Right now I am using `setInterval()` function with a time of 5 seconds. This will call the DB query in each 5 seconds.

**Is there a better way to listen to DB changes without the `setInterval()` functionality?**

**My code sample is**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    setInterval(check_new_notification, 5000);
});

socket.on('check_new_notification', function(user,time){
    check_new_notification(user,time);
});

function check_new_notification(user,time){
    if(user == '' || typeof user == 'undefined' || user == null){
        user = user_id;
    }
    if(time == '' || typeof time == 'undefined'){
        time=0;
    }
    if(user != '' && typeof user != 'undefined' && user != null){
        db.getDetails(user,time,mysql,pool,function(error,result,row_count){
            io.emit('trigger_alert',result, row_count);
        });
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to listen to DB changes. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Does MySQL support such real-time notifications?

Comment: As a side note you most probably don't have to test the truthiness (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) of your variables in so many ways. A simple `if(shouldbe && !shouldnotbe)` should do the trick and makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to avoid active polling in your case. 
So your approach is basically correct.

To improve performance, do the following:

- Create a table with a boolean field `status`
- Set `status` to true if something notification-worthy happened
- Read `status` in Node.js
- If true: Do the select and set `status` to `false`
- If false: Do nothing

Make sure, that your operations are atomic -> Use Transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the notification functionality where the notification is beeing created. For example, have your application push a message to a queue when the database row has been inserted. Your application may then subscribe to the queue and update when a new row has been inserted. Optionally you could send your complete notification through your message queue.

Comment: This is good advice, if he controls the code that's pushing data into the DB server; which wasn't clear to me me from his question.  The app could possibly be monitoring a DB that's being used by another (or several other) apps.